# Terraform Cognito Identity Pool Authentication Provider

Tags: terraform, amazon-cognito

I have a question regarding to AWS Cognito Identity Pool Setup in Terraform.
So, i am trying to create identity pool, authentication provider as per the UI.(Screenshot below)
[image: AWS Identity Pool UI Creation Page]

I was reading up on terraform or AWS docs and realise there is no example on how i could create Cognito Type Authentication Provider. I seen examples like Google or Facebook being shown in their docs and created as per code below. I assume this "supported_login_providers" is referring to authentication provider. But will like to ask for advice or help in how can i create a Cognito Based Authentication Provider?

```
    supported_login_providers = {
    "graph.facebook.com"  = "7346241598935552"
    "accounts.google.com" = "123456789012.apps.googleusercontent.com"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `cognito_identity_providers` to refer to a Cognito authentication provider:

```
cognito_identity_providers {
    client_id = aws_cognito_user_pool_client.my_user_pool.id
    provider_name = aws_cognito_user_pool.my_user_pool.endpoint
}
```

You should also create `aws_cognito_user_pool_client`, and `aws_cognito_user_pool` with your terraform script.